# How ListCreateAPIView works?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am just new to the Django Rest Framework and I want to clearly understand how ListCreateAPIView works.
We just can provide a `queryset`, `serializer_class` and it will create a read-write endpoint.

I was looking for info on the official doc but didn't find what I want.

Any information will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the story begins from the `get` method so when calling get it will call `list` method
this is how list method looks like it will call queryset and make pagination then serialize the data to returned as response

```py
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    
            page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
            if page is not None:
                serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
                return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
    
            serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

for more information, you can visit this link
https://www.cdrf.co/3.12/rest_framework.generics/ListAPIView.html

Answer (score 2):

`ListCreateAPIView` is a generic APIView that allows for GET (list) and POST (create) requests.
You can read the [source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/71e6c30034a1dd35a39ca74f86c371713e762c79/rest_framework/generics.py#L232) and maybe get a better understanding

Basically, `ListCreateAPIView` has the method `get()` which will call the method `list()` in [`mixins.ListModelMixin`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/71e6c30034a1dd35a39ca74f86c371713e762c79/rest_framework/mixins.py#L33). The `list` method will instance the serializer, filter, paginate the queryset and return a response based on the queryset and serializer you have defined in your class.

If you want a deeper understanding I recommend you to read the source code, it can be confusing at first but when you starting using it you will understand it better.